# Delphi 7 failing to pickup username and password from UDL

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm having issues trying to get Delphi 7 to connect to a remote MSSQL server.
This is the extent of the code:

```
  UDLPath := 'FILE NAME=C:\Path\To\UDL.UDL';
  TestConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  with TestConnection do
    begin
      ConnectionString := UDLPath;
      try
        Connected := True;
      except
        ShowMessage('Failed');
      end;
    end;
```

I get the error "Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection"

I have LoginPrompt set to false in the IDE. I tried setting it to true, but it's hitting the except before it prompts for a login.

The test connection button works in the UDL, and I can connect to the server through SSMS.

I've tried using a raw connection string with the userid and password fields set properly, but that didn't work.

Comment: I belive you have to write 
TestConnection.ConnectionString := 'FILE NAME=' + UDLPath

Comment: @JensBorrisholt I've got it wrapped in a with block.

Comment: have you tried copying and pasting the actual connection string from the udl file as the connection string rather than loading the file?

Comment: @TobyAllen I just did. No luck.

Comment: What type of component is `TestConnection` exactly?  When I use IBO or DBX components to connect to databases, they have username/password properties/params.  Does your `TestConnection` component have those?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's a TADOConnection. I don't think it does, but I'll take a look in the morning when I'm at my computer.

Comment: @mpthrapp: when using an MSSQL Provider with `TADOConnection`, you can include `User ID` and `Password` parameters in the `TADOConnection.ConnectionString` value, eg: `UDLPath := 'C:\Path\To\UDL.UDL'; UDLUserName := ...; UDLPassword := ...; ConnectionString := 'FILE NAME='+UDLPath+';User ID='+UDLUserName+';Password='+UDLPassword;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yup, I tried that with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the provider. The native client 10 driver was failing to authenticate for an unknown reason, but the ODBC for SQL driver worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you, see the two links:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889615

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/01/17/sql-server-fix-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection-microsoft-sql-server-error-18452/